# Adding enum to namespace in TypeScript causes namespace merge error

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, namespaces

Here's what i've got

```
namespace X {
   export namespace Y {...}
   export class Y {...}
}
```

When I try and add an enum to Y (like exhibit B), such that my code now looks like this:

```
namespace X {
   export namespace Y {
       export enum E {...}
   }
   export class Y {...}
}
```

I get a compilation error 
"A namespace declaration cannot be located prior to a class function with which it is merged"

Exhibit A

[image]

Exhibit B
[image]

Question: How do I tie a namespace to an enum that's already being exported?

Comment: Good question, did you find any answers?